# Displaying Actual progress of a background task with a progress bar

Tags: android

I have background task and i would like to display a Determinate Horizontal progress bar while it runs. I want the user to be able to see the actual progress of the process therefore i cant use an indeterminate progress bar.

Here is the background task i would like to display a progress for:

```
  ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("invite", params,
            new FunctionCallback<String>() {

                @Override
                public void done(String object, ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.i("tag", "user create has run");
                    if (e == null) {

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "successful" + mPhone, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                    } else {
                        String errorMessage = e.getMessage().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                    }

                }

            });
```

I have thought about using an AsyncTask, but this `ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground`  piece of code creates a new thread for itself and runs its task on it. So when i call it in the do in background of an AsyncTask, the moment it reaches this part of the code it creates a new thread for the task, i.e leaving the thread created by the AsyncTask's doInBackground. Then because no more work is being done on its thread the doInBackground ends and onPostExecute is called while the task is still being run on a thread it created. Making whatever progress i was displaying useless.

Is there a way i could get the progress of the process and display a Determinate Horizontal progress bar for it?

Comment: You can use onProgressUpdate()  refer http://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-downloading-file-by-showing-progress-bar/

Comment: No, the problem is that inside doInBackground there's another thread, so doInBackground immediately finishes. onProgressUpdate would jump straight to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Ignore this, I guess this won't work and you need an `AsyncTask`:

*If that function already runs in background, you don't need an `AsyncTask`. From your snippet, `done` function is called when it's done, so it's the same case as a `postExecute`. If you have some intermediate function to get the progress, you can use `Looper.getMainLooper()` to attach back to the main thread.*

The other option is using `Looper.myLooper()` to get the thread from `ParseCloud` and join it with the thread of the `AsyncTask`, so `doInBackground` doesn't finish right away.

*Update: this is easier:*

You can simply use `runOnUiThread` (I'm using runnable in a new thread to simulate ParseCloud):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mTextProgress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_progress);

    Button slowButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_slow);
    slowButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mTask.execute((Void[]) null);
        }
    });
}

private void updateUi(int i) {
    mTextProgress.setText(String.valueOf(i));
}


Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i += 10) {
            try {
                final int finalI = i;
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        updateUi(finalI);
                    }
                });
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
};

private AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> mTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>() {

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        mTextProgress.setText(values[0].toString());
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        new Thread(mRunnable).run();
        return null;
    }
};
```

Comment: The second option sounds like the best...could you give me an example.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try it.. so I should put my function inside the runOnUiThread?... Is there a way I could display the progress in a determinate horizontal progress bar...so the user can see exactly how far the progress is...

Comment: Put the progress information inside runOnUiThread. In my example, the method run itself runs in background, but at each iteration it posts an update on ui thread. This is the same way that an AsyncTask works with publishProgress.

Comment: If your method is a black box that does a lot of things and you can't insert publishProgress or runOnUiThread in the middle of it, then you're out of luck and will need to use indeterminate progress bar.